# Is there a quick way to assign unique text entries in an array a number?

Tags: matlab

In MatLab, I have several data vectors that are in text. For example:

```
speciesname = [species1 species2 species3];
genomelength = [8 10 5];
gonometype = [RNA DNA RNA];
```

I realise that to make a plot, arrays must be numerical. Is there a quick and easy way to assign unique entries in an array a number, for example so that RNA = 1 and DNA = 2? Note that some arrays might not be binary (i.e. have more than two options).

Thanks!

Comment: What sort of plot do you think you will be doing? You can change the axis text to represent words as well, if you are interested in something like that.

Answer (score 0):

So there is a quick way to do it, but im not sure that your plots will be very intelligible if you use numbers instead of words.

You can make a unique array like this:

```
u = unique(gonometype);
```

and make a corresponding number array is just `1:length(u)`

then when you go through your data the number of the current word will be:

```
find(u == current_name);
```

For your particular case you will need to utilize cells:

```
gonometype = {'RNA', 'DNA', 'RNA'};
u = unique(gonometype)

u = 

'DNA'    'RNA'

current = 'RNA';
find(strcmp(u, current))

ans =

   2
```